# Spring AOP and Post Construct

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, aop, aspectj, postconstruct

I want to write the name of method which is using with @PostConstruct. But I found that AOP is unable to "Around" the PostConstruct method.
Is there any way to use AOP with PostConstruct method?

Comment: Do you always want to write the method name if @PostConstruct is used? Or just for some methods?

Comment: Yes, Dactabird. I want to write the name of PostConstruct method.

Answer (score 5):

Give this a try.

```
    @Around("@annotation(javax.annotation.PostConstruct)")
    public void myAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint jp) throws Throwable{
        System.out.println("This is before " + jp.getSignature().getName() + "()");
        jp.proceed();
    }
```

Additionally you need to activate compile-time weaving. I published a Demo project on github which uses maven. Clone https://github.com/jannikweichert/PostConstructAOPDemo and execute

```
mvn clean compile spring-boot:run
```

After that you should see in the Sysout:

```
This is before test()
test() is executed
```

Enjoy!

Comment: It does not work. It works for other annotation but @PostConstruct :(

Comment: You need to activate compile-time weaving. I'll edit my answer above.

Answer (score 3):

The @PostConstruct and @PreDestroy annotations are part of J2ee library  and not part of Spring AOP. So By default, Spring will not aware of the @PostConstruct and @PreDestroy annotation. To enable it, you have to either register ‘CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor‘ or specify the 
as 
 ‘ in bean configuration file,

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

<bean class="org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

<bean id="mybean" class="mypackage.MyBean">
    <property name="myPropertyName" value="my value" />
</bean>
```

Or as

```
<bean id="myBean" class="mypackage.myBEan">
    <property name="myProperty" value="test message value" />
</bean>
```

and annotate your method

```
@PostConstruct
public void myMethod() throws Exception {
  System.out.println("PostConstruct : " + myProperty);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Spring AOP is proxy based. Unless configured to do otherwise, **`Spring AOP performs run-time weaving`** and `@PostConstruct` executes at load time of an application.

To enable `@PostConstruct` to be executed by `@Around` advice at load time you have to set up Spring [load-time weaving](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#aop-aj-ltw). Once setup use `@annotation` as a binding form for `@Around` advice, as follows:

```
@Around("@annotation(javax.annotation.PostConstruct)")
public void logAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("method name: " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
}
```